# Hover + Active CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have 4 images. When you move over the images (:hover) they get scaled and bright. A cursor also appears when you hover over the images. If you click on the image, it disappears and and the text appears. My problem is that the text stays after I click on the image. But the text must go away and the image must come back. I'm only working with CSS. Is there a way to bring back the image is when it is not active?

CSS:

```
.pic > .back{
display:none;
}

.pic:active > .back {
display: block;

}

.pic:active> .front{
display:none;

}
.pic:hover{
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pic">
<div class="front">
    <img src="jeanrover.png" alt="Jean Rover Pic"/>
</div>
<div class="back">
    <?php jeanRover(); ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Who sets the `active` class on the button click? Revert the class on text being clicked.

Comment: What do you mean by button?